# InnerText returns undefined in content script Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to access HTML elements with [`content scripts`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts), however I get undefined on innerText although using `run_at: document_end` in `manifest.json`.

My `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "my extension",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["http://127.0.0.1:8000/*"],
        "js": ["jquery.js", "script.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
      }
  ]
}
```

script.js:

```
var address = $('.house span').innerText;                         
alert(address);
```

The webpage on http://127.0.0.1:8000 has a `div` with class `house` and a span element in it. The alert returns undefined, but when using it in the console it returns the actual innerText.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

innerText is not a property of jquery. use text or html method as per requirement

```
var address = $('.house span').text();   
var address = $('.house span').html();   
var address = $('.house span')[0].innerHTML;
```